# About indentation in LaTeX

Tags: indentation

Is there any LaTeX command allowing to indent a *whole* paragraph **but** its first line ?

I tried by compiling the text then, knowing where starts a new line, inserting a `\quad`. However, for long paragraphs, this forces to recompile more and more times because adding `\quad` changes the point of each line breaks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On TeX level there's `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.

Comment: There's also the [hanging](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hanging) package. Its user guide describe the package as "provid[ing] facilities for both hanging paragraphs and hanging punctuation".

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 1ex
\newenvironment{reverseindent}[1]
  {\par\noindent\hspace{-\dimexpr#1\relax}\leftskip=#1\relax\ignorespaces}
  {\par\leftskip=0pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{reverseindent}{1cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{reverseindent}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is _exactly_ what I was searching for; unfortunately it seems to conflicts with other packages I uses. Do you know which packges could affect your suggestion?

Comment: @NandoBici Perhaps the name `reverseindent` is already taken, as that is the only new name I introduce.  Just rename `reverseindent` to something else (e.g., `Rindent`), and try again.